# How can i add color drop chips into a table using jQuery? This is a connect four game

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, frontend

https://github.com/Mo-Xiyad/Front-end.git

**This Code is a part of the Connect-Four game.**

I'm having a problem with dropping the color chip into the table.
when I click on the table it's displaying the player1 name as the winner and there is no chips on the table.

I'm not so sure if I'm having a problem with the (checkBottom) function (undefined).

I would like to know how I can fix this problem.

```
var player1 = prompt("Player One: Enter Your Name , you will be Blue");
var player1Color = 'rgb(254, 228, 64)';

var player2 = prompt("Player Two: Enter Your Name, you will be Red");
var player2Color = 'rgb(255, 107, 107)';

var game_on = true;
var table = $('table tr');

function reportWin(row,col) {
  console.log("You won starting at this row,col");
  console.log(row);
  console.log(col);
}

function changeColor(rowIndex,colIndex,color) {
  return table.eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).find('button').css('background-color',color);
}

function returnColor(rowIndex,colIndex) {
  return table.eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).find('button').css('background-color');
}

function checkBottom(colIndex) {
  var colorReport = returnColor(6,colIndex);
  for (var row = 6; row > -1; row--) {
    colorReport = returnColor(row,colIndex);
    if (colorReport === 'rgb(128, 128, 128)') {
      return row
    }
  }
}

function colorMatchCheck(one,two,three,four){
  return (one===two && one===three && one===four && one !== 'rgb(128, 128, 128)' && one !== undefined);
}

// Win Checks
// Check for Horizontal Wins
function horizontalWinCheck() {
  for (var row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row,col+1) ,returnColor(row,col+2), returnColor(row,col+3))) {
        console.log('horiz');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Check for Vertical Wins
function verticalWinCheck() {
  for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row+1,col) ,returnColor(row+2,col), returnColor(row+3,col))) {
        console.log('vertical');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Check for Diagonal Wins
function diagonalWinCheck() {
  for (var col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row+1,col+1) ,returnColor(row+2,col+2), returnColor(row+3,col+3))) {
        console.log('diag');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row-1,col+1) ,returnColor(row-2,col+2), returnColor(row-3,col+3))) {
        console.log('diag');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Game End
function gameEnd(winningPlayer) {
  for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
      $('h3').fadeOut('3000');
      $('h6').fadeOut('3000');
      $('h1').text(winningPlayer+" has won! Refresh your browser to play again!")
    }
  }
}


var currentPlayer = 1;
var currentName = player1;
var currentColor = player1Color;

// Start with Player One
$('h6').text(player1+": it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your chip.");

$('.board button').on('click',function() {

  // Recognize what column was chosen
  var col = $(this).closest("td").index();

  // Get back bottom available row to change
  var bottomAvail = checkBottom(col);

  // Drop the chip in that column at the bottomAvail Row
  changeColor(bottomAvail,col,currentColor);

  // Check for a win or a tie.
  if (horizontalWinCheck() || verticalWinCheck() || diagonalWinCheck()) {
    gameEnd(currentName);
  }

  // If no win or tie, continue to next player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer * -1 ;

  // Re-Check who the current Player is.
  if (currentPlayer === 1) {
    currentName = player1;
    $('h6').text(currentName+": it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your chip.");
    currentColor = player1Color;
  }else {
    currentName = player2
    $('h3').text(currentName+": it is your turn, please pick a column to drop your chip.");
    currentColor = player2Color;
  }

})
```

Comment: Just make console.log on each step. First check the the attribute col has a value at var bottomAvail = checkBottom(col); So you make a console.log('col', col). If it has a value check the checkBottom function step by step with console.log. So you will find the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have an extra row, here you have the code working correctly:

```
var player1 = prompt ('Jugador 1: Ingresa tu nombre, tu color es el azul');
var player1Color = 'rgb(86, 151, 255)';

var player2 = prompt('Jugador 2: Ingresa tu nombre, tu color es el rojo');
var player2Color = 'rgb(237, 45, 73)';

var game_on = true;
var table = $('table tr');

function reportWin(rowNum,colNum) {
  console.log("Vos ganaste en esta row,col");
  console.log(rowNum);
  console.log(colNum);
}

function changeColor (rowI, colI, color){
    return table.eq(rowI).find('td').eq(colI).find('button').css('background-color', color);
}

function returnColor (rowI, colI){
    return table.eq(rowI).find('td').eq(colI).find('button').css('background-color');
}

function checkBottom(colI) {
  var colorReport
  for (var row = 5; row > -1; row--) {
    colorReport = returnColor(row,colI);
    if (colorReport === 'rgb(128, 128, 128)') {
      return row
    }
  }
}

function colorMatchCheck(uno,dos,tres,cuatro){
  return (uno===dos && uno===tres && uno===cuatro && uno !== 'rgb(128, 128, 128)' && uno !== undefined);
}

// Chequeo victoria ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Chequeo horizontal
function horizontalWinCheck() {
  for (var row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row,col+1) ,returnColor(row,col+2), returnColor(row,col+3))) {
        console.log('horiz');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Chequeo vertical
function verticalWinCheck() {
  for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row+1,col) ,returnColor(row+2,col), returnColor(row+3,col))) {
        console.log('vertical');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Chequeo Diagonal
function diagonalWinCheck() {
  for (var col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
      if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row+1,col+1) ,returnColor(row+2,col+2), returnColor(row+3,col+3))) {
        console.log('diag');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else if (colorMatchCheck(returnColor(row,col), returnColor(row-1,col+1) ,returnColor(row-2,col+2), returnColor(row-3,col+3))) {
        console.log('diag');
        reportWin(row,col);
        return true;
      }else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Fin del Juego
function gameEnd(winningPlayer) {
  for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
      $('h3').fadeOut('3000');
      $('h1').css('color', currentColor);
      $('h1').text(winningPlayer+" ha ganando!");
      $('h6').text("Si quieren jugar otra vez actualice la página!");
    }
  }
}

var currentPlayer = 1;
var currentName = player1;
var currentColor = player1Color;

// Comienza con el jugador 1
$('h6').text(player1+": Es tu turno. Selecciona una columna para dejar tu ficha");

$('.board button').on('click',function() {

  // Identifica la columna
  var col = $(this).closest("td").index();

  // Obtiene la fila disponible en esa columna
  var bottomAvail = checkBottom(col);

  // Lanza la ficha a la fila disponible de la columna seleccionada
  changeColor(bottomAvail,col,currentColor);

  // Chequea victoria
  if (horizontalWinCheck() || verticalWinCheck() || diagonalWinCheck()) {
    gameEnd(currentName);
    game_on = false
  }

  // Si nadie ganó cambia el jugador
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer * -1 ;

  // Chequea el jugador
  if (game_on) {
      if (currentPlayer === 1) {
        currentName = player1;
        $('h6').text(currentName+": Es tu turno. Selecciona una columna para dejar tu ficha");
        currentColor = player1Color;
      }else {
        currentName = player2
        $('h6').text(currentName+": Es tu turno. Selecciona una columna para dejar tu ficha");
        currentColor = player2Color;
      }
  }

})
```

And the HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Conecta Cuatro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <h1>Bienvenido a Conecta Cuatro!</h1>
        <h3>Conecta 4 fichas para ganar!</h3>
        <h6>Comencemos!!</h6>

        <table class="board">
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
                <td><button type="button"></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```